# How to filter by an object property in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

How do I filter using the symbol column?  The symbol column contains objects of type: `zipline.assets._assets.Equity`

I am able to print the symbol using:

`print df.iloc[0][1].symbol`

```
                        date               symbol   pension    mutual
0  2013-12-31 00:00:00+00:00  Equity(45971 [AAL])  14353441  27482858
1  2014-03-31 00:00:00+00:00  Equity(45971 [AAL])   9386708  46218086
2  2014-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  Equity(45971 [AAL])   8988341  61937025
3  2014-09-30 00:00:00+00:00  Equity(45971 [AAL])   9699814  77006037
4  2014-12-31 00:00:00+00:00  Equity(45971 [AAL])  12409152  81555692
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use apply. Here's a toy example:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo({})".format(self.a)

In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[Foo(1), 1], [Foo(1), 2], [Foo(2), 3]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
        0  1
0  Foo(1)  1
1  Foo(1)  2
2  Foo(2)  3

In [13]: g = df.groupby(df[0].apply(lambda x: x.a))  # Note: x is of type Foo
```

These Foo `a` attributes are the name attribute (the keys) of each group.
Hence we can filter using that:

```
In [14]: g.filter(lambda x: x.name == 1)
Out[14]:
        0  1
0  Foo(1)  1
1  Foo(1)  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Dataframe df from Andy Hayden's answer you can also do this:-

```
In [13]: df[df[0].map(lambda x: x.a == 1)]
Out[13]:
       0  1
0  Foo(1)  1
1  Foo(1)  2
```

You can also filter by many values by doing the following:-

```
In [14]: df[df[0].map(lambda x: x.a in [1,2])]
Out[14]:
        0  1
0  Foo(1)  1
1  Foo(1)  2
2  Foo(2)  3
```